# Struct to function who spect void*

Tags: c++, opencv, void

I have a function like that:

```
void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *roi){
roi->foo=foo;
....
}
```

and I want to call it sending a struct like that:

```
struct Roi{
    Point point1, point2;
    int drag;
    Rect rect;
    Mat img, roiImg;
    int select_flag;
};
struct Roi roi;
cvSetMouseCallback("image", mouseHandler, (void*)&roi);
```

I have problems because I don't know how to do it... Help pls

Comment: So you want the mouse handler function take in the `Roi` struct as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to cast `roi` from `void*` to `Roi*` before you can access the members.

```
Roi* realRoi = static_cast<Roi*>(roi);
realRoi->foo=foo;
```